# Python initialize class with list/mutable attribute

Tags: python, class, initialization

If I want to initialise a class which has a list attribute, then I can directly assign an list to the attribute in the class **init**.

Doing this however would just be an assignment of list reference, and my class attribute would be changed if I update the original list.

What is the best way to initialise a python classes with a list attribute? Should I use an list copy/deepcopy instead, or is it ok to ignore the issue above and just rely on people discarding the list that they use for initialisation?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr

arr = [1,2,3]
a = A(arr)
print(a.arr)
arr[0] = 100
print(a.arr)
```

Comment: At first you should drop the term "array". You are using a **list**. Lists many differences compares to arrays (like for example in C). And in Python the term refers to numpy arrays or the arrays from the array module. And for your question: a `self.arr = arr[:]` should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks makes sense, I have adjusted array->list

Comment: Guess what would be most useful behavior for the specific use case and, very important, write appropriate documentation describing the behavior.

Comment: Take a copy. Whether a shallow or deep copy is required will depend on your particular use-case

Answer (score 0):

there is no  best way for initializing such a class, because the true answer is, that it depends on the purpose of your class and maybe the side effects, which you would/could provoque in it(not recommended for sure :)).

So if you would like to work with an array/list, which are all **mutable** data structures I would **copy/deepcopy** them in my ***init***, just to be sure that nothing happens out of the scope on your class, following the **LEGB** (local, enclosing, global or builtin scope convention).

So as you've mentioned in your pos, I would always **copy** the input just to be sure that nothing happens out of the class scope. Good luck :)